# Cómo resolver un <unresolved overloaded function type>? (callback templatizado)

Tags: c++

Estoy intentando tempatizar un calback de esta forma

```
template<typename T>
T GetValue(T (*CallBack) (const string), string in)
{
    T value;

    try
    {
        value = CallBack(in);
    }
    catch(std::invalid_argument &e)///if no conversion could be performed
    {
        cout << "Error: invalid argument: --> " + string(e.what());
        exit(-1);///terminar el programa
    }
    return value;
}

int main()
{
    int integer=0;
    string data;
    cin>>data;
    integer=GetValue<int>(&std::stoi, data);
    return 0;
}
```

Pero me esta dando este error:

> error: cannot convert "|unresolved overloaded function type|" to "int
> (^)(std::string)" {aka int (^)(std::__cxx11::basic_string)}

Creo que no está reconociendo esto **&std::stoi** y no veo la forma de como hacer que funcione.

¿Alguien sabe que es lo que está fallando realmente?

[Esté es el enlace al manual de referencia de stoi()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol)

Muchas gracias!!

Comment: Esa función realmente tiene **3** argumentos: [`int stoi( const std::string, size_t *, int );`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol). No es posible obtener un puntero a una versión de ella que solo tenga uno.

Comment: Muchas Gracias por tu respuesta